# datagridview inside of tabpage to bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have an dataGridView which is inside of an TabPage. Now i need to create an image of the dataGridView, but i looked online for solutions and i found DrawToBitmap but that only takes a part of the dataGridView.

This is the code i am using right now

```
bm = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView2.Width, this.dataGridView2.Height);
dataGridView2.DrawToBitmap(bm,new Rectangle(100,100, his.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Instead of `100,100` use `0,0`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thats just a padding

Comment: If you need any padding around the drawing, add the padding to the bitmap size too. `var padding = 100; var bm = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.Width + 2 * padding, dataGridView1.Height + 2 * padding);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to fit a `DataGridView` onto a `Bitmap`, even **if its content is larger** than the `DataGridView` or the `TabPage` or even the `Form`.

The trick is to **temporarily** enlarge the `DataGridView` for the `DrawToBitmap` call so that all cells fit in and no scrollbars are there. Afterwards set it back to the original size that fits your layout..:

```
Size oldsize = dataGridView1.ClientSize;
var tw = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(x => x.Width).Sum();
var th = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Height).Sum();

dataGridView1.ClientSize = new Size(tw + dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth, 
                                    th + dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.ClientSize.Width, dataGridView1.ClientSize.Height);

using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) 
       dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, dataGridView1.ClientRectangle);

bmp.Save(yourFilename, ImageFormat.Png);

dataGridView1.ClientSize = oldsize;
```

If you want **padding** around it you can simply make the `Bitmap` **even larger still** and write out the target rectangle's coordinates explicitly, instead of using the `ClientRectangle`..